# Firebase make security rule to allow get size of query only

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

If you can't understand title, I'm sorry. So, I wrote  my code.

```
let query = await db.collection('collection').where('what', '==', false).get();
console.log(query.size);
```

I will make security rule make to allow only this situation. How can I?
(I'm really sorry because I can't speak english very well. But I need your help. please)

Answer (score 1):

This security rules gives Access only when the property is false and only for read operation. Write operation is completely prohibited. Here is a code:

```
match /collection/{documentId} {
    allow read: if resource.data.what != false
    allow write: if false
}
```

If you want to know more about Cloud Firestore Security Rules check [this article](https://medium.com/@khreniak/cloud-firestore-security-rules-basics-fac6b6bea18e)